# AWS Amplify Authenticator usernameAlias

Tags: aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify Authenticator component with Cognito for authentication. Does Authenticator already detects and change label from username to email if Cognito Userpool signin type is email?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't - amplify creates auto-generated usernames